# Build tree from table

Tags: c#

I define the following class Node in order to get the relation parent/child

```
class Node
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        public Node Parent { get; set; }
        public IList<Node> Children { get; set; }

        public Node()
        {
            Children = new List<Node>();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            //return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " " + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => x.Id));
            return "Node: " + Operator + " " + Id + " "
            + string.Join(",", Children.Select(x => string.Format("({0}, {1})", x.Sign, x.Id)));
        }
}
```

I have the following table as example

```
PNLId   PNLCode PNLParentId Operator    Sign
0      
49  C   51  +   NULL
50  Z   51  +   NULL
51  Y   107 /   NULL
52  B   107 /   NULL
53  B   108 +   NULL
```

I wrote the following script in the main  :

```
var map = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
var rootNodes = new List<Node>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLId"]);
    int? parentId = null;
    if (!row.IsNull("PNLParentId"))
    {
        parentId = Convert.ToInt32(row["PNLParentId"]);
    }
    string op = Convert.ToString(row["Operator"]);
    string sign = Convert.ToString(row["Sign"]);
    map[id] = new Node
    {
        Id = id,
        ParentId = parentId,
        Operator = op,
        Sign=sign

    };
}

foreach (var pair in map)
{
    if (pair.Value.ParentId.HasValue)
    {
        var parent = map[pair.Value.ParentId.Value];
        pair.Value.Parent = parent;
        parent.Children.Add(pair.Value);
        parent.Operator = pair.Value.Operator;
    }
    else
    {
        rootNodes.Add(pair.Value);

    }
}
```

In this case it will return ,for the PNLParentId 107

```
[107 Node: + 107 (, 51),(, 52)]
```

which is wrong it should be

```
[107 Node: / 107 (, 51),(, 52)]
```

How can I modify the code above to Build node tree first. Then start at the root nodes copying the operator from the children. Progress to the children and copy their children's operator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the code you have written to build the tree.
Here is some test data to work with (I don't have the database tables you have):

```
var map = new Node[] {
    new Node() { Id=0, ParentId=0, Operator="", Sign=null}
    ,new Node() { Id=1, ParentId=null, Operator="+", Sign=null}
    ,new Node() { Id=2, ParentId=3, Operator="+", Sign=null}
    ,new Node() { Id=3, ParentId=4, Operator="/", Sign=null} 
    ,new Node() { Id=4, ParentId=4, Operator="/", Sign=null} 
    ,new Node() { Id=5, ParentId=1, Operator="+", Sign=null} 
};
```

And here is the fixed code:

```
// remove Value
var rootNodes = new List<Node>();
foreach (var pair in map)
{
    if (pair.ParentId.HasValue) 
    {
        var parent = map[pair.ParentId.Value]; 
        pair.Parent = parent; 
        parent.Children.Add(pair);
        parent.Operator = pair.Operator;
    }
    else
    {
        rootNodes.Add(pair);    
    }
}
```

Changes are:

- Added rootNodes
- Removed .Value

After you have run it, the rootNodes collection will contain 1 element (the one with Id=1) and the map array will contain correct object references to its parents.

**Explanation:**

The `pair` variable belongs to the `foreach` loop and contains elements of `map`. 
The variable `map` is an array of `Node` objects, which is a class in which you have declared the property `Parent` - which is also of type `Node`.

Variables of type `Node` are all object types, not value types and hence they don't own the `.Value` property. 
But the `ParentId`, which you have declared, is a nullable value type, because of the declaration `int?` - and all **nullable** value types (note the `?` suffix) have the `.Value` property: 
So for `ParentId`, you can obtain the value using `ParentId.Value` (and `.HasValue` to check for null), but not for `Parent`, which is a `Node` object. `Node` object's properties need to be accessed directly by their property names.

Comment: Why to remove  .Value ? I didn't get it .

Comment: @user3548593: I have edited the answer of user3615347 and added an explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user3548593: You can test the code from this answer in [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) (a tool which is free) - just put it into the `main()` method, add `rootNodes.Dump(); map.Dump();` at the end, then add the `Node` class from your question. If you run the example you see the recursive structure being built in the output window: One of the benefits of the `.Dump()` method LinqPad provides!